# How to use yasnippet's tab expansion in minibuffer?

Tags: yasnippet, minibuffer

I use yasnippet to insert some symbols (e.g., ✔), and I would like to do that in minibuffer too.  When I press `TAB` in minibuffer, it said " is undefined".  How to define it to use yasnippet?  Is it safe to do that?

Answer (score 2):

After adding the following 3 lines of code, I can use my snippets defined in org-mode, by pressing `TAB` inside minibuffer:

```
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'yas-minor-mode)

(yas--define-parents 'minibuffer-inactive-mode '(org-mode))

(define-key minibuffer-local-map [tab] 'yas-expand)
```

Comment: You may want to bind to `yas-maybe-expand` (unquoted) in case you still want normal `TAB` behaviour when not in front of a snippet abbrev key. http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-expansion.html#sec-1-1

Answer (score 1):

Bind `TAB` or whatever to whatever command you want (e.g. some yasnippet command) in the *minibuffer keymaps*.

See (elisp) [Text from Minibuffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Text-from-Minibuffer.html) and [Completion Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Completion-Commands.html) for info about the minibuffer keymaps.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.  Let me add more details and codes I got.